# Force init.gradle to run, or otherwise install custom gradle logger

Tags: logging, gradle

I have code in init.gradle:

```
useLogger(new CustomEventLogger())
class CustomEventLogger extends BuildAdapter...
```

and if I run gradlew -I init.gradle build, it works great
HOWEVER

This is checked into source control - I don't want to have to tell everyone who checks it out that they have to add -I init.gradle - in fact I might never meet those people - so I want to have some way of either

- putting that code in the build script
- putting something in the build script to forece run init.gradle

I've tried putting the above code into the build script, and it just gives me a "could not find method uselogger" - and all the googling I've done about auto running init scripts seems to involve home directories or environment variables - neither of which I can control on some arbitrary user's machine.

Anyone know how I install a custom logger without needing the user of my build.gradle to do anything special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code into your build.gradle but change it to

```
gradle.useLogger(new CustomEventLogger())
```

This is equivalent to `project.getGradle()` and will give you [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html) object which is the home for `useLogger` method.

Comment: thanks heaps... however - new probelm - now it complains about my customeventlogger class - saying it's not a task? any ideas?

Comment: Make a new question :) No ideas short enough for a comment